Next.js 14.x middleware.ts not triggering
I have a app/middleware.ts but it didn't trigger,
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))
}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: '/about/:path*',
}




When I visit /about, it didn't redirect to /home, does anyone know what the problem is? 
All the structure are shown on the pictures.

I’m voting to close this question because the majority of the content is screenshots which violates this guideline: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557

middleware.ts should located in the root of your project. not the app directory

For NextJs 14.x the middleware.js or middleware.ts file is used to define middleware that runs on the server before a request is fully processed.

It allows you to alter the response based on the incoming request by performing actions like rewriting, redirecting, adjusting request or response headers, or even directly sending a response.

To define middleware, use the middleware.js or middleware.ts file located in the root of your project. Such as at the same level as the app or pages directory, or inside the src folder if applicable.

Example of possible folder and file structures:
root level:
project-root/
│
├── app/
│   ├── rest of the code 
│
├── pages/
│   ├── rest of the code 
│
├── middleware.ts
│
└── package.json

inside src folder:
project-root/
│
├── src/
│   ├── app/
│   │   ├── rest of the code 
│   │
│   ├── pages/
│   │   ├── rest of the code 
│   │
│   ├── middleware.ts
│
└── package.json


For more read the NextJs Docs.

